# Google finance as an argument for ArrayFormula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B:B)=1, "Share Price", IF(ISBLANK(B:B), "", googlefinance(B:B, "price"))))
```

I am trying to make row 1 (my header row) have a name, and then below that, if a valid ticker symbol is an input in column B, have google finance fetch the price of that stock. However, I am getting N/A in all of the cells underneath "share price" and can't figure out why.

Help please.

edit: Link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lyYYzLrFHfjojlL27bQ6ligNz2DBVpSM24jYfAVBVQs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 I've edited the original post to include a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GOOGLEFINANCE` is kinda ArrayFormula already so this will not work as you would expect...

you will need to use script:

```
function onOpen(e){this.arrayThis("C1:C");}    //COLUMN WHERE YOU WANT TO HAVE THE RESULT
function arrayThis(range){
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(range).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(range).getCell(1,1).getFormula());
}
```

where C1 needs to be:

```
=IF(ROW(B1)=1, "Share Price", IF(B1="",,GOOGLEFINANCE(B1, "price")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I appreciate your answer, as this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. However, there is one major piece of functionality that still isn't working. If I add a new row at any point and populate it with a new ticker, the sheet doesn't update the info, even after rerunning the script. It's like the script doesn't know a new column was added.

Comment: did you try to change onOpen to onEdit ?

Comment: I tried that but it still does not work. When I add a new column, the formula does not populate into it.

Comment: Hi @Warstolrem ! I have tried @player0 solution and it did work for me. Moreover, I tried adding a column between ```Ticker``` and ```Share Price``` and between ```Company Name``` and ```Ticker``` and the equation is still been performed (indeed, the reference of the formulas change for example from ```C1``` to ```E1```). Could you please share a screenshot of your issue or let me know if I did the same steps as you did? Also, have you added ```=IF(ROW(B1)=1, "Share Price", IF(B1="",,GOOGLEFINANCE(B1, "price")))``` to ```C1``` before running the function? Thanks !

Comment: I hope this displays the problem better, the row for TSLA was created after the original program was run, however, numerous edits have happened and the sheet does not populate. I have also tried using onOpen and reopening the page to no avail: https://imgur.com/a/yHegPDX

Comment: Also, I made an error in saying column, I intended to say row. @MateoRandwolf

Comment: pretty sure you cant have multiple onEdit or onOpen functions. see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131081/186471

Comment: and: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8500693?hl=en&msgid=10570817

Comment: Great, that seems to have solved the problem. Thank you so much. Do you have any optimization tips? It takes quite a while to load. @player0

Comment: sry, scripts are not yet my strong side so I can't rly say I have. maybe @MateoRandwolf may have some insights?

Comment: Hi ! ```onEdit()``` is triggered **everytime** a change is done in the sheet. Thus, for increasing efficency maybe try the following : put all the calls to ```this.ArrayThis``` in the same ```onEdit()``` function (i.e, only have one ```onEdit()``` with all the calls to the functions on it). Let me know if that increases the speed.

Comment: With an answer this complex I'd rather copy the formula for now :-( . I appreciate it though for situations where I will need the automation.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following formula in the cell C1:

```
=MAP(B:B,LAMBDA(ticker,IF(ROW(ticker)=1,"Share Price",if(isblank(ticker),,GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker,"price")))))
```

### Explanation

This is a new method since the introduction of `LAMBDA` and its helper functions in Google Sheets in August 2022.

Some inconveniences of `GOOGLEFINANCE` may now be solved by using `MAP(LAMBDA)` around it instead of `ARRAYFORMULA`. The trick here is, as far as I understand, that `MAP(LAMBDA)` calculates the specified formula for each row in the input array separately (effect similar to manually expanding the formula over the whole range), whereas `ARRAYFORMULA` passes the whole array as an argument to the formula (`GOOGLEFINANCE` is special and doesn't work intuitively with such input).

This general method can be used to pass another arguments to the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function in a similar way, that is from specified ranges. If one of such specified arguments should be start_date (in this case without end_date|num_days specified), then we additionally need to use `INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(),2,2)`, because the output of `GOOGLEFINANCE` with start_date (and no end_date|num_days) will be a 2×2 array, where only the last value is the one we need.

### Another example

A similar problem that I struggled with, to better illustrate this method: assume that we want the conversion rates between currencies specified in ranges A2:A, B2:B (with their appropriate three letter codes), in each case from a date specified in range C2:C. The solution would be the following formula in cell D2:

```
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(currency_1,currency_2,date,INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:" & currency_1 & currency_2,"price",date),2,2)))
```