# How to integrate GOOGLEFINANCE results in an array formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

Following ARRAYFORMULA is giving me an error "***parameter 1 value is invalid.***"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B), "",  GOOGLEFINANCE(B2:B, "price")))
```

B column of my sheet contains the stock symbols whose value I wish to fill in my sheet. Example below

```
Company Name
GOOG
ADBE
MSFT
```

Can someone help here?

Comment: Can you show an example of the values you have in B2:B?

Comment: @Jescanellas added the values

Comment: That's odd, because I used the same values and formula and it returns 1211.45, without any errors. Try with another Sheet in incognito mode and see how it goes.

Comment: didn't work for me.....

Comment: `GOOGLEFINANCE` is not supported in array formulas.

Comment: @kishkin I am not disagreeing with you. But I was wondering if you had a link to back that up?

Comment: @DarcyThomas sorry, no link to back that up. Google lacks (or I totally missed that) a good deal of details in Sheets formulas docs. One of those details would be the ability of some functions to work inside of `ARRAYFORMULA` (`GOOGLEFINANCE`, `FILTER`, `INDEX`, etc.) So, the knowledge is from experimenting. And it is a common knowledge now, I've seen a lot of answers like this. "Not working inside `ARRAYFORMULA`" means that the function won't be called for every element `ARRAYFORMULA` iterates over. Though a function's results (a single value or a range) could be used in `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Comment: @DarcyThomas I just checked if `GOOGLEFINANCE` works in `ARRAYFORMULA` once again, just in case. As of now it does not. But that could change with time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google finance as an argument for ArrayFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874426/google-finance-as-an-argument-for-arrayformula)

Answer (score 3):

This questions seems to be a duplicate of [Google finance as an argument for ArrayFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874426/google-finance-as-an-argument-for-arrayformula). I have answered it with more detail. As a new user I'm only able to post an answer here, I cannot comment/flag as duplicate.

Anyway, assuming stock symbols are in range B2:B, then you put the following formula in cell C2:

```
=IFERROR(MAP(B2:B,LAMBDA(company,GOOGLEFINANCE(company,"price"))))
```

This is a new method since the introduction of `LAMBDA` and its helper functions in Google Sheets in August 2022.

The trick here is, as far as I understand, that `MAP(LAMBDA)` calculates the specified formula for each row in the input array separately (effect similar to manually expanding the formula over the whole range), whereas `ARRAYFORMULA` passes the whole array as an argument to the formula (`GOOGLEFINANCE` is special and doesn't work intuitively with such input).

Answer (score 2):

`LAMBDA` and friends are available, so this works:

```
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(row, IF(row = "",, GOOGLEFINANCE(row, "price"))))
```

[image]

---

**Old story:**

`GOOGLEFINANCE` cannot be used in array formulas. You'll have to extend your formula downwards.

For example this formula should be in every cell from `C2` and down:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$B)), GOOGLEFINANCE($B$2:$B, "price"), "")
```

[image]