# Fill dynamically GOOGLEFINANCE function

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic

I have a table with list of stocks of shares with its day today transactions. I want to add a column with its current NAV. I can as well add the function at each row as

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2)
```

in column I. But I would like to automatically fill the column as a new row in added. How can this be achieved?

Regards,
Pravin Kumar.

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google finance as an argument for ArrayFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874426/google-finance-as-an-argument-for-arrayformula)