# ARRAYFORMULA with another ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets

im trying to get the ratio, between BTC!E:E and LIST!D:D on BTC:F1

simpolified example with static values, cos i get data from other sheets and spreadsheets

values from BTC!A:A are filtered from LIST!A:A, so LIST!A:A > BTC!A:A but values from BTC are in LIST

in this example i have some failed attemps, tried some others with query, wwith no result

[EXAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JL2qojKfROjyLDXd1xqy1bJVjHHumeKHOsBc1C4xvIE/edit?usp=sharing)

another question, is it possible to use ARRAYFORMULA with GOOGLEFINANCE?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);"";IFERROR(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2;"closeyest")))
```

currently im using that in all rows, also tried without sucess as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google finance as an argument for ArrayFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874426/google-finance-as-an-argument-for-arrayformula)

Answer (score 0):

no. GOOGLEFINANCE is a type of ARRAYFORMULA already so it all depends how you use it and what are you after. for example, if you trying to get multiple tickers as array it is not possible but if you trying to get closed values for 1 ticker on an array of dates it is possible

Comment: yea i figured that, thats why i asked if it was possible as a second question highjacking my own post, thanks, anyway any tips on my main question