# Automatic filling of Stock price

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, stock, google-finance, automatic-updates

I have a list of scrips of stock market. When I add a new scrip in a new row, I would like to automatically fill its current price using GoogleFinance function of google sheets.

In the attached google sheets, Column A contains the mnemonics of the scrip from which column B calculates the current price. When I add a new scrip, I copy the formula to the new row. How do I achieve it automatically?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google finance as an argument for ArrayFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874426/google-finance-as-an-argument-for-arrayformula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GOOGLEFINANCE` is already a type of `ARRAYFORMULA` so it is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`. this means that it is not possible to process your A column with one single formula. you have only two options how to do this:

- use script which will detect new entry in A column and insert single-cell `GOOGLEFINANCE` formula adjacent to it
- hardcode it like:

---

```
=IFERROR({GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2);
          GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A3);
          GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A4);
          GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A5);
          GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A6);
          GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A7);
          GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A8);
          GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A9)})
```